# Has a dodgy driver for Logitech wireless mouse appeared

Tags: drivers, mouse, logitech

Two wireless Logitech mouse models: M310 and the smaller M185 have recently started to misbehave when using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic on different PCs.  They do not stop completely just have intermittent major latency.

They were fine when first purchased in the last 12 months. Changing the surface has helped the M310.  I now stick a magazine with lots of typing under it which ameliorates the problem.

Has some dodgy driver come out in a kernel update?

Comment: it is possible both are operating on the same channel and interferring with each other's signal?

Comment: Sorry for tardiness.  A: No.  They are seldom used at the same time.  I mostly keep the smaller M185 offline and use it out with a portable laptop.

Comment: ok. too bad that was my idea. maybe someone else has another idea.